# Is there a AWS Redshift alternative to Athenas EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-redshift

I am searching for a way to "profile" an SQL query that runs in AWS Redshift database.

Redshift does support "EXPLAIN" - which does describe the execution plan, however
Athena for example supports "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" which shows data on the actual query execution.

Is there something similar for Redshift?

**Notes:**

1. A solution which does not require access to the Redshift console is preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVL_QUERY_SUMMARY and SVL_QUERY_REPORT system views may help
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-analyzing-the-query-summary.html